# Native sandbox mode (Google Apps Script) not supported in Chrome 29+

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

I've been writing a small script for the company that I work for in Google Apps Script.

I use the NATIVE Sandbox mode in Google Apps Script to ensure speed and compatibility with latest css and jquery functions.

Since Chrome 29 (and 30 via the dev channel), Chrome seems unable to support the NATIVE Sandbox mode and will only use the EMULATED mode.

This means several features of my site breaks (datepicker won't insert dates etc.) and it's a lot slower.

**Is anyone seeing the same? How should I contact Google about this? (Will they even want to fix it?)**

To make sure that it's not something in my scripts making Chrome incompatible, I've run an extremely simple page and asked it to be run in NATIVE sandbox mode. It doesn't work in Chrome 29+.

I've installed Chrome 28 via a portableapps package, and it does support NATIVE mode.

Thank for any answers in advance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, reported as [Issue 2954](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2954). Visit and star it to receive updates.

Comment: Thank you. I hope Google will post an answer to that issue. I've starred it to follow updates.